# Singleton WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, singleton

It took 30 minutes to initialize the resources of a 3rd party java library which is converted to .NET assemblies and plug-ins in mine wcf service every time when I call it from my client application.

I want to initialize it only once and then want to re-use that instance for subsequent client calls.Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Having a singleton of your service will only give you drawbacks like error handling, multithreading, etc. It will not give you better performance in most cases. Find out why it takes 30 minutes and try to fix that bug.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question peer but its not a bug.It is code which takes 30 minutes only for first time for initialization.I only don't want to initialize it again and again when client will call it.This code is inside my WCF service.